# Difference between EMA and EWMA?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

I recently came across the term EMA (Exponential Moving Average) and EWMA (Exponential Weighted Moving Average) in Time Series Data. I am not able to figure out the difference between these two? Also I want to know how to implement the EWMA in pandas.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Moving Average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and [Weighted moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Weighted_moving_average)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with writing code at all, and instead is a question about terminology for a specific problem domain. It [should be answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ema+vs+ewma); there might be a Stack Exchange website that would accept the question, but Stack Overflow is definitely not it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Also I want to" Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We expect **one** question at a time, which should be clear, specific and show an attempt at doing research and solving the problem independently first.

Answer (score 0):

**EMA** is EWMA, the key is to understand why do we need something **Exponentially**, compared with the simplest average **SMA**, you might know it's all related to time:

Recently, stocks' prices, and COVID-19 concern us more than 10-20 years ago's Lehman Brothers and the dot-com bubble, talking to how they influenced the price and economics, we might want to put weight/ratio on them to calculate the consequence we assume, something decay within time, you can feel it.

---

Let's prepare the data to plot the **EMA**, let's say we wanna see an apple:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
df = data.DataReader(['AAPL'], 'yahoo', start='2022/02/15', end='2022/06/21')
df = df['Adj Close'].round(2)
print(df.tail())
```

Output

```
Symbols       AAPL
Date              
2022-06-14  132.76
2022-06-15  135.43
2022-06-16  130.06
2022-06-17  131.56
2022-06-21  135.87
```

And here's **EMA**

```
# we take 5 for every EW moving average
df['AAPL-ema'] = df.iloc[:,0].ewm(span=5).mean()
print(df)
```

Output

```
Symbols       AAPL    AAPL-ema
Date                          
2022-02-14  168.63  168.630000
2022-02-15  172.54  170.976000
2022-02-16  172.30  171.603158
2022-02-17  168.63  170.368154
2022-02-18  167.05  169.094360
...            ...         ...
2022-06-14  132.76  137.133554
2022-06-15  135.43  136.565703
2022-06-16  130.06  134.397135
2022-06-17  131.56  133.451423
2022-06-21  135.87  134.257616
```

and the plot:

```
df[['AAPL','AAPL-ema']].plot(figsize=(15,6))
```

Output
[image]

---

In default, `adjust` is activated, it divide by **decaying** adjustment factor
[image]

it leads to different weights on price and varied over time.

Refer to [pandas.DataFrame.ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html)

there are still tons of arguments we need to concern, `adjust`, `alpha`, `com`, etc.